# problems with creating a header file

Tags: c, header, struct

Okay, I have a main source called `main.c`, a header file called `test.h`, and another class called `handBeraknare.c`.
Im trying to make my code a bit more readable by transfeering some of my methods to the class `handBeraknare.c`.

So in `main.c` i have a struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct kort{
  int draget;
  char farg;
  int nummer;
  struct kort *next;
  }kort; `
```

In `main.c` i create a couple of these using `kort k=(kort*)malloc(sizeof(kort));` and put them into an array. What im trying to achive is to send this array of `kort` to a function in `handBeraknare.c` but I get some sort of weird error `"in file included from handBeraknare.c"`.

Im gussing this has to do with the headerfile now knowing what `"kort"` is (my struct). Anyway, here's some of the code:

```
// in test.h
int beraknaFarg(kort kortHand[]);



// in handBeraknare.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"
int beraknaFarg(kort kortHand[]){
 char c = kortHand[0].farg;
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<5;i++){
        if (kortHand[i].farg!=c){
                                 printf("inte färg");
                                 system("pause");
           //Spelaren har inte färg. Retunera 0
           return 0;
           }
         }
      //Spelaren har färg. Retunera 1 
       printf("!!!!färg");
                                 system("pause");  
      return 1;
}


//part of the main class. Calling function test() 
// which calls the method beraknaHand which exists in handBeraknare.c

#include "test.h"
...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  test();
}

// the testfunction in my mainclass
void test(){
       char farg[4]={'S','K','R','J'};
       int nummer[14]={0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
       kort kortArray[52];
       kort kortHand[5]; 
                  kort *k;
                  k=(kort*)malloc(sizeof(kort));              
                  k->farg='s';
                  k->nummer=5;
                  kortHand[0]=*k;

                  k->farg='s';
                  k->nummer=11;
                  kortHand[1]=*k;

                  k->farg='s';
                  k->nummer=12;
                  kortHand[2]=*k;

                  k->farg='s';
                  k->nummer=11;
                  kortHand[3]=*k;

                  k->farg='s';
                  k->nummer=9;
                  kortHand[4]=*k;
    beraknaFarg(kortHand);
```

Comment: You have provided insufficient information. What does handBeraknare.h look like? And can you provide the exact error message please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make test.h to read

```
typedef struct kort{ 
      int draget; 
      char farg; 
      int nummer; 
      struct kort *next; 
      } kort;
int beraknaFarg(kort kortHand[]);
```

and remove the `typedef` from main.c

Comment: Got it to work. It was simply a matter of syntax error. I declared the typedef in my header, and removed it completley from main.c. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the typedef in the header file,  and then include the header file in the C file you want it to use it.
in addition , because it is typedef defintion and not declaration , you need to define it in the C file.
I.E
h file:

```
typedef strcut   
{  
   int a;  
   ....  
}t_struct_type;
```

c file:

```
t_struct_type struct_var;
```

if you want to use struct_var in more than one c file , you need to add the `extern` keyword in the h file. like this : extern t_strcut_type struct_var

Comment: Was a bit confused by your answer. but +1 for a working solution. I removed the whole typedef declaration from main class, and declared it in my header file instead. I might add that im using the struct in both main and in handberaknare, without using the extern keyword :)